# Check if number starts with certain digit

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance

My question is how can I check if the student number for undergraduates start with a digit 5 and those for post graduates start with a 9.

The condition is as follows:
For undergraduate students the initial registration fee is R500 and for postgraduate students the initial registration fee is R600. For undergraduate modules the fee is R1100 per module and for postgraduate modules the fee is R2000 per module.

I have already setup both my classes and my main looks as follows but iam not sure where I should do the condition checking in the main or in my implementation file?

```
    //Application
    #include "Student.h"
    #include "PostGradStudent.h"
    #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
        double regFee, modFee, addFee;

        PostGradStudent thePostGradStudent(1, 2, 3, 54321012, "Rohan", 2, "Hole-In-One avenue", "BSc", "Thesis");
        thePostGradStudent.displayInfo();

        return 0;
    }
```

The below is where I did the calculation but here is where I do not understand how I can send the correct values to main ?

```
    double PostGradStudent::calcFee() //calculate the total fees(registration fee + module fees + any additional fee) for a student
    {
        return regFee + modFee + addFee;
    }

    void PostGradStudent::displayInfo()
    {
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout << "Details for the student" << endl
             << "Student Number: " << get_studentNumber() << endl
             << "Student Name: " << get_studentName() << endl
             << "Number of Modules: " << get_noModules() << endl
             << "Address: " << get_address() << endl
             << "Degree: " << get_degree() << endl
             << "Total cost of fees: R" << setprecision(2) << calcFee() << endl
             << "Dissertation: " << get_dissertation() << endl;
```

}

I have attached a screenshot when I run the application below:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU99m.jpg)

Assistance in this regard will be much appreciated.

Thank you
Rohan

Comment: Turn the number into a string and check the first character? `std::to_string(123).at(0) == '9' // false`.

Comment: @Bathsheba where should the check be done in main ?

Comment: @RohanvanAswegen: You apply my transformation to  the return of `get_studentNumber()`

Comment: @Bathsheba thank you will I also then declare the amounts(registration fee, module fee etc.) in the condition you gave under get_studentNumber ?

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is your number and is an integral type, then

`while (n < -9 || n > 9) n /= 10;`

transforms `n` to the first digit. Drop the `n < -9 ||` part if you don't support `signed` `n`.

This also has the neat property that `0` is invariant.

Doing this numerically will be faster than transforming to a `std::string`, but if you are working essentially with strings (to my mind at least a student number is not something on which you would want to perform arithmetic operations), then use `substr` &c.

Answer (score 0):

Having a number you can use the [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) function to convert it to string. In case you are using a compiler which doesn't support C++11 try looking at [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) function.

After the conversion is done, it is enough to check the specified `string` or `char[]` item using the `[]` operator.

As @muXXmit2X denotes also `std::ostringstream` can be used for the conversion. 
Actual solution choice depends on the details of your requirements.

Sample implementations:

```
// check if the 'value' has digit '2' set in the hundreds pos
// assumption: there are at least 3 digits
uint32_t value = 21245;
char check = '2';

// substr
std::string text = std::to_string(value);
bool isTrue1 = text.substr(text.size()-3, 1) == std::string(1, check); // true
bool isTrue2 = text[text.size()-3] == check; // true

// itoa
char buffer[10];
itoa(value, buffer, 10);
bool isTrue3 = buffer[strlen(buffer)-3] == check; // true

// numerical
bool isTrue4 = (value / 100 % 10) == 2; // true
```

Comment: _In case you are not using a compiler which doesn't support C++11 try looking at a itoa function_ or use `std::ostringstream`.